# how to use specific toolchain in Eclipse

Tags: makefile, eclipse-cdt

I have met with some issues in using the toolchain in Eclipse. I need the tool chain for cross compilation purpose

Currently my build method is to use makefile and I always have to

- source
- export LD=

But is it possible to use the information in  for setting up Eclipse CDT.

I have tried to create the C/C++ Settings>Environment variables with the same environments settings as my . However it always run into error when i build

```
Error: Program "make" not found in PATH
```

my path in the environmental setup file is as follows:

```
  /opt/R3linux/sysroots/x86_64-R3linuxsdk-linux/usr/bin:/opt/R3linux/sysroots/x86_64-R3linuxsdk-linux/usr/sbin:/opt/R3linux/sysroots/x86_64-R3linuxsdk-linux/bin:/opt/R3linux/sysroots/x86_64-R3linuxsdk-linux/sbin:/opt/R3linux/sysroots/x86_64-R3linuxsdk-linux/usr/bin/../x86_64-R3linuxsdk-linux/bin:/opt/R3linux/sysroots/x86_64-R3linuxsdk-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-R3linux-linux:/opt/R3linux/sysroots/x86_64-R3linuxsdk-linux/usr/bin/aarch64-R3linux-linux-musl:$PATH
```

Just like to know what is wrong? and what steps have i missed out in configuration steps

REgards

Comment: do you have `make` installed?

Comment: @ti7 isnt make already installed in eclipse...or better to say i have previously use the same eclipse setup to compile native program

Comment: AFAIK specialized Eclipse-based IDEs can make this easier. For example STM32 CubeIDE lets the user just specify a cross toolchain and sets the path automatically. It also comes with its own make, so both internal and external builders work.